# Configuring aspell to support UTF-8 encoded texts

Tags: latex, aspell

I have installed apell 0.50.3 on my Windows 10 system. I want to check LaTeX documents like this "demo.tex":

```
\doucmentstyle{article}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Übersicht}
\end{document}
```

When I run the spell checker with this command

```
aspell --encoding utf-8 -c -t demo.tex
```

I get this output

```
\doucmentstyle{article}
\begin{document}
\chapter{+£bersicht}
This cahpter has some wrong words.
\end{document}
```

The word "cahpter" is marked, since it is misspelled. So far so good. But the encoding UTF-8 is not accepted. The chapter title is displayed wrongly.

If I use a config file "aspell.conf" containing the line

```
encoding utf-8
```

and start

```
aspell --conf=aspell.conf -c -t demo.tex
```

the result is the same.

Does aspell support displaying and checking of non-ASCII code? How should I configure aspell to check my UTF-8 encoded texts?

Answer (score 1):

Aspell 0.50 doesn't support encoding. Use aspell 0.60 instead. Unfortunately this version is not available on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Aspell does support UTF-8 encoding on Windows 10. The key is in setting the environment variable `LANG` to the desired locale. For example, `set LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. It took me hours to figure this out.

You can install the current version of Aspell using [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/):

```bsh
pacman -Syu
pacman -S aspell-devel aspell6-en
```

To install the German dictionary:

```bsh
curl -o aspell-de.tar.xz https://repo.msys2.org/mingw/x86_64/mingw-w64-x86_64-aspell-de-20161207-2-any.pkg.tar.xz
cd /
xz -d aspell-de.tar.xz
tar xf aspell-de.tar.xz
mv mingw64/lib/aspell-0.60/* usr/lib/aspell-0.60
```

In Windows add `C:\msys64\usr\bin` to the user %PATH% and use a launcher script to execute aspell:

```
@ echo off
set LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
aspell.exe %1
```

You can combine English and German spell checking with the one-liner (described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170822081659/https://lembra.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/check-spelling-on-multiple-latex-files-using-multiple-languages/)):

```bsh
 cat file.tex | aspell --lang=en_US list | aspell --lang=de_DE list
```